# How to curve rectangle outwards in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes

Is there a way to curve a rectangle outwards (give arc shape effect, see attached image)? Or do I have do it manually using the pen tool by adding anchors to the rectangle line? I have also tried to do it with arc Up and arc down horizontal (make with warp) tool. But its a complex process. Is there any simpler and better way to do it?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could use an "Inflate" warp on the rectangle...

[image]

Either using an effect (*Effect → Warp → Inflate...*), or using an envelope distortion (*Object → Envelope Distort → Make With Warp...* then "Inflate" from the Style dropdown).

You can "apply" the distortion by going to "*Object → Expand/Expand Appearance*" if needs be.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the **curvature tool** to curve specific lines of an object.

If you want to do that for a rectangle, click on the rectangle, then click on 
a line, click the curvature tool and drag the line.